# Find column whose name contains a specific value that is in a fixed column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column names, and I want to find the one that contains a certain value. I'm searching for the value in the column 'segment' in column names like '...._segment'.
I want the column name to be returned as a string or a variable, so I access the column later with df['name'] or df[name] as normal. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luhcS.png)

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I was able only to search a fixed string. For example: selected_cols =[x for x in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('402')]]

Comment: Please share your code. Here are some instructions. Note the "no screenshots" warning. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether you want to get the column names which contain the string you want or the columns name of the columns which have at least one value that contains the string you want.

if the dataframe is:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd 
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'a_1': ['b_1', 'b_2'], 'b_1': ['a_1', 'a_2']})                                                                             
In [2]: df                                                                                                                                            
Out[2]: 
   a_1  b_1
0  b_1  a_1
1  b_2  a_2
```

for the first case, if you want to find all the column name that match `a_*`:

```
In [3]: import re                                                                                                                                     
In [4]: columns = [col for col in df.columns if isinstance(col, str) and re.match('a_.*', col)]                                                       
In [5]: columns                                                                                                                                       
Out[5]: ['a_1']
```

for the second case, if you want to find all the columns in which there is at least one value that match `a_.*`:

```
In [6]: columns = [col for col, ser in df.iteritems() if ser.str.match('a_.*').any()]                                                                 
In [7]: columns                                                                                                                                       
Out[7]: ['b_1']
```

in which:

`df.iteritems`: return a iterator of (column name, column values (series)) pairs.

`Series.any`: return `True` if any value in the series is `True`.